# CalendarView in UWP C# showing wrong day

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, calendar, calendarview

I have CalendarView on two pages. 
First page is used to add records to calendar by assigning the selected date to the database record.

Second page is used to show all records assigned to the selected date.

Now, when on the first page I assign date to the product by clicking the date manually, on the second page product is shown correctly when selected date that corresponds to the products date.

However, when on the first page I add dates to the products programmatically, on the second page, these products are shown one day before than they should.

I have no idea what is happening. I will post code if you want to check something.

THe problem is strange, becaue on one calendar these automatically added dates are shown for example on 5th April, but on the second calendar they are listed under 4th April.

Is that the globalization of two calendars problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the problem. It was in deed issue with DateTimeOffset/DateTime values.

I changed every instance of Date I found in the code by appending it with

> .LocalDateTime

.

This way I got the correct local date of each DateTimeOffset object and data is added to/ pulled from the Calendar correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Locale(globalization ) would be a potential problem. But having code would help us to provide you more info.